# Show that both graphs drawn below are isomorphic by giving an isomorphism for them. (Petersen Graph)

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

The question that I'm trying to answer is: "Show that both graphs drawn below are isomorphic by giving an isomorphism for them. Also known as the [Petersen Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WZdy.png).

I dont quite understand what is meant by 'give an isomorphism'. What is the best method to answer questions such as this one?

Comment: Just pair off the vertices in one with the vertices in the other, so that adjacency is preserved.

Comment: You're saying I should number each of the vertices of the first graph such that (for example) a =1 , b =2 , c = 3, etc. And to then show that there are edges between the same vertices?

Comment: That's it${}{}$!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Two layouts of the Petersen graph]

A sample isomorphism for your graphs is relatively simple here if you know that the Petersen graph is [strongly regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph), meaning that the choice of starting point for your isomorphism is arbitrary.

So we can map between the two diagrams starting with an arbitrary three-point arc, so taking mapping pairs of $(a,1),(b,2),(c,3)$ we can continue the 5-cycle with $(e,9),(f,10)$ then completing adjacent sets we have $(d,4), (i,5), (k,8), (h,6),(g,7)$  giving a full isomorphism:

$$(a,1),(b,2),(c,3),(d,4),(e,9),(f,10),(g,7), (h,6), (i,5), (k,8)$$

Due to the strong regularity, we can pick any starting point, any of its adjacent points then any further adjacent point to map to a given arc of three points on one graph, giving $10\times 3\times 2= 60$ different isomorphisms to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing nothing about the Petersen graph, I decided to follow Lord Shark's advice:

> "Just pair off the vertices in one with the vertices in the other, so that adjacency is preserved."

The hard part would be guessing how to pair off the vertices; once that was done, it would be easy to check if adjacencies were preserved.

The first thing I noticed about the graph on the right is that ***it has a cycle of length nine:*** $1,2,3,6,8,10,9,7,4.$ If the graphs are isomorphic I should be able to find a nine-cycle in the other one. Sure enough, after a couple of false starts, I found one: $a,f,k,i,g,d,h,c,b.$ After that I just did what came naturally and tried matching one cycle with the other: $1\to a,\ 2\to f,\ 3\to k,\ 6\to i,\ 8\to g,\ 10\to d,\ 9\to h,\ 7\to c,\ 4\to b$ and of course paired the leftover vertices: $5\to e.$

Then I check adjacencies. Luckily, everything worked!